# Getting access to the keys of an array of objects in es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, key

i'm new to es6 and i have an array of objects like below:

```
checkProps = [ {symbol: rwerwe}, {side: Buy}, {status: Hey} ]
```

With a for loop i want to create a string like: 
myurl = localhost:3000/symbol=rwerwe&side=Buy&status=Hey

For this i have to get access to the keys of each object and use concat for the string composition. I used Object.keys but it returns integers. I want something to return the symbol, side and status. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```js
var checkProps = [ {symbol: 'rwerwe'}, {side: 'Buy'}, {status: 'Hey'} ];
var urlStr = 'localhost:3000/';
var urlParams = [];
checkProps.forEach(function(o) {
  var keys = Object.keys(o);
  keys.map(function(key) {
      urlParams.push(key + '=' + o[key])
  });
});

urlStr += urlParams.join('&');
console.log(urlStr)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array and apply `Object.keys` to the items.

```
const parameters = checkProps.map(item => Object.keys(item).map(key => key + "=" + item[key])[0])
                             .join("&");
const myUrl = `localhost:3000/${parameters}`;
```

It's a bit cleaner with ES2017 and `Object.entries`:

```
const parameters = checkProps.map(item => Object.entries(item)[0])
                             .map(parameter => parameter.join("="))
                             .join("&");
```